# Can IntelliJ sources directories, classes, and methods / members list in project tab be set with the same display / behavior than in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I'm going from *Eclipse* to *IntelliJ*.

Is there a way in *IntelliJ* to have the same display and behavoir for projects sources directories, classes and methods than in *Eclipse* ?

1. Direct access to source folder without having to unfold : src, then main, then java (3 clicks).
2. Methods and members list under each class when unfold. I don't know where they are listed for a class.

[image: Compared IntelliJ / Eclipse display of Java classes in a project]

Comment: In IntelliJ, to achieve 2, you can turn on Show Members, from the Options menu (Gear-Icon) in the project side-panel.

Comment: I've checked "_Show members_" on the gear but I still have to do four extra clicks to open `BalanceComptesCommunesDataset` : src, main, java, fr.ecoemploi...., then my class.